# Python requests token for REST API keeps returning 401 unable to determine proper token format

Tags: python, access-token

I have this working in Powershell, but i'm trying to figure out how to get it working in Python. In Powershell i just use

```
$webclient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $auth")
```

with passing to $auth my b64Val of my username and password combo, then getting my token string and again passing it as to the same format using Authorization and Basic with $auth containing my long token string.

However, i keep getting 401 returned over in python trying to fig out how to do the same.. here is my sample python code, the first request to get My_token works fine..

```
password = 'myPassword'
usrPass = "admin:" + password

b64Val = base64.b64encode(usrPass.encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")
My_token=requests.get("https://10.10.1.2/api/login",headers={"Authorization" : "Basic %s" % b64Val}, verify=False)

token_contents = My_token.content.decode("utf-8").replace('"', '')

#token_test = 'Token ' + token_contents
token_test = 'token ' + token_contents
#token_test = 'TOK:' + token_contents
#token_test = 'Basic ' + token_contents
#token_test = 'token=' + token_contents

header = {'Authorization' : token_test}

url = 'https://10.10.1.2/api/types/instances'
r = requests.get(url, headers=header, verify=False)
```

see my commented lines i tried all different types of token settings.

my thoughts were i had to convert the token from bytes to string and remove the double quotes from it , the My_token.content original value property looks like so.

```
b'"YWRtaW46MTU2OTE4NzkwMgg3NzpjZDdlZWEyNmI2NDJmOTY0ZmI5ZGQ3YzBiNnI2ZTNlZQ"'
```

Just trying to fig out what i'm misunderstanding with taking the My_token object which works fine and logs me in , but then return the token back on the next request i am trying to perform. thanks

[UPDATE and FIX]

thanks to stovfl's comments i was able to learn more and see my mistakes. i was over thinking this and making it more complex than needed to be ;). I just needed to KISS and just basic auth with my token contents lol.

r_test = requests.get('https://10.10.1.2/api/types/instances', auth=("admin", token_contents), verify=False)

Comment: Read about [basic-authentication](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)

Comment: thx i had and auth=HTTPBasicAuth works fine just the same as i have now. where i'm having issues is sending the token string back that i received, on the next requests call i make, if you see my code. i tried all sorts of diff combos of the value token in doing research for python, i commented out the different ones i tried, all result in a 401 un-authorized response. i thought using {'Authorization' : 'token <token_results>'} would be the one to work but none of the examples i have above would work for token

Comment: As it stands, you **dont't send** `auth=` in your second `.get(...`. Read about [persistant - session-objects](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects). ***"i tried all different types of token 'settings"***: Don't **try**, ask the stuff at `REST API`.

Comment: thx, you lead me down a different path, i see my mistake and misunderstanding now. i just edited with my changes

Comment: Just one last note, when you set `verify=False` you are no longer securing your network connections.